# How to pass parameter for sproc via C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I have a MVC application that runs the following sproc named sp_GetEmployeeByID:

```
    @ID int = 0
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT @ID, *
    from tblEmployee
    where ID = @ID
```

and the method that calls this needs to pass the int parameter however I cant seem to figure this out, here is what i have so far:

```
public Employee GetSingleEmployee(int ID)
        {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["KVKDb"].ConnectionString;
            Employee emp = new Employee();

            using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand sprocCmd = new SqlCommand("sp_GetEmployeeByID " + ID, connect);                sprocCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                connect.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = sprocCmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read() == true)
                {
                    Employee employee = new Employee();
                    employee.ID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["ID"]);
                    employee.City = rdr["City"].ToString();
                    employee.DateOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["DateOfBirth"]);
                    employee.Gender = rdr["Gender"].ToString();
                    employee.Name = rdr["Name"].ToString();
                    emp = employee;
                }
            }
            return emp;
        }
```

The obvious issue is that there is no sproc named sp_GetEmployeeByID int ID. I want to know how to call that sproc and pass a parameter for the sprocs @ID parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `Parameter` to the command:

```
SqlCommand sprocCmd = new SqlCommand("sp_GetEmployeeByID");                       
sprocCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
sprocCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID)
```